# How to override default width with !important to dynamic width by adding new class

Tags: html, css

I need to override default css that is set by `width:70% !important` to `width:100% !important` by adding new class.
Also i want to keep existing class and css like:

`.abc{
   width: 75% !important;
}`

And overriding css will be

`.newAbc{ 
  width: 100% !important 
}`

In this case, newly added css need to override existing css!

Is there any way that it will workout?

Comment: If you load the second css file after the first file that adds the !important your second css will "override" the first one. Only solution here, or use jquery

Comment: @prasad,Is there any way that existing css and overriding css both can works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `!00%` to `100%` for CSS rule to be valid.

```css
.abc {
  width: 70% !important;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: 5px;
}

.newAbc {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="abc"></div>
<div class="abc newAbc"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 options here.

1. Change '!00%' to '100%'.
2. Put the second css class after the first (newabc AFTER abc)
3. If you have a parent class to reference, add that before hand

```css
.abc{
   width: 75% !important;
}

.parent .newAbc{ 
  width: 100% !important 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle. 
https://jsfiddle.net/trupti11/wLxepqvq/1/

HTML

```
<div class="main">
<div id="d1" class="box a1"></div>
<div id="d2" class="box a1"></div>
</div>
<br/>

<div id="b1" class="btn">Add width</div>
<div id="b2" class="btn">Remove width</div>
```

JS

```
   $('#b1').click(function() {
    $('#d2').addClass('a2');
    })

    $('#b2').click(function() {
    $('#d2').removeClass('a2');
    })
```

CSS

```
.main { display:block; width:500px; height:120px; border:solid 2px #666; }
.box { background-color:#ffc; display:block; position:relative; border: solid 1px #666; height: 50px; }
.btn { background-color:#fcc; display:block; position:relative; border: solid 1px #666; height: 20px; margin: 5px; padding: 5px; width:100px; }
.a1 {width: 50% !important; }
.a2 {width: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: why downvote? This can be helpfull where you need to add different sized widths to divs.